# Cannot read property of undefined when using exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

I have the following Express app:

**router.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var exch = require("../exchanges/exch")();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    exch .getTicker((tick) => {
        res.send('get ticker exch: ' + JSON.stringify(tick));
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

**exch.js**

```
var Kraken = require('kraken-api');
var moment = require('moment');
var _ = require('lodash');

/**
...code
**/

var Exchange = function(config) {
  _.bindAll(this);

  if(_.isObject(config)) {
    this.key = config.key;
    this.secret = config.secret;
    this.currency = config.currency.toUpperCase()
    this.asset = config.asset.toUpperCase();
  }

  this.pair = addPrefix(this.asset) + addPrefix(this.currency);
  this.name = 'kraken';
  this.since = null;

  this.kraken = new Kraken(this.key, this.secret);
}

Exchange.prototype.getTicker = function(callback) {
  var set = function(err, data) {
    if(!err && _.isEmpty(data))
      err = 'no data';

    else if(!err && !_.isEmpty(data.error))
      err = data.error;

    if (err)
      return console.log('unable to get ticker' + JSON.stringify(err));

    var result = data.result[this.pair];
    var ticker = {
      ask: result.a[0],
      bid: result.b[0]
    };
    callback(err, ticker);
  };

  this.kraken.api('Ticker', {pair: this.pair}, _.bind(set, this));
};

}

module.exports = Exchange;
```

As you can see I am including the object via `require("...")()`. However, I still get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'getTicker' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTicker' of undefined
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/ticker.js:20:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
>       at router (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating an instance, thus you can't access a method on the prototype. You're actually just calling the constructor function `Exchange` exported by `exch.js`. Since the constructor function, when called directly, returns nothing (implicitly `undefined`), you get the error:

```
var exch = require("../exchanges/exch")(); //exch is undefined because Exchange as a function returns nothing
```

This does not setup the prototype because you haven't constructed an object, just called the function. Instead, use `new` to construct a new `Exchange` object:

```
var Exchange = require("../exchanges/exch");
var exch = new Exchange();
```

This will create a new `Exchange` object in which you can call `getTicker` from the prototype. Note: Make sure to pass `config` to the constructor!

---

Without `new` you could do a check in `Exchange` to see if you accidentally called it without `new`, and to return a new instance:

```
var Exchange = function(config) {
  if(!(this instanceof Exchange)) {
    return new Exchange(config);
  }
  //...
}
```

What this does is return a new instance of `Exchange` even if you called the function directly. Now you could use:

```
var exch = require("../exchanges/exch")();
```

But I would always prefer the former method of using `new` *always* for constructors.

Answer (score 0):

`require("../exchanges/exch")()` call the function rather than create a new instance, use `new` to instantiate in order to use the `prototype`. The reason you got `undefined` is that the `Exchange` returns nothing. You suppose it to be a `constructor`, but you call it as `function`

Use the code instead:

```
var exchModule = require("../exchanges/exch")
var exch=new exchModule()
```

Answer (score 0):

change last line of your code in exch.js

```
exports.exchange = Exchange;
```

now modify in router.js

```
var exch = require("../exchanges/exch").exchange;

var exchObject= new exch();
```

now you can use **exchObject** object to call methods

Comment: and thanks for highlighting it, i was not aware about it.